# How to insert a two-column figure in the current page when using LaTeX?

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column

I know there is a command like

```
\begin{figure}[p]
\end{figure}
```

But when I use it in a two-column model, the `$[p]$` cannot work. So I am wondering if there is any solution to preserve the figure in current page when I use `$\begin{figuire*}$`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the starred variant with `[t]` option and move the code up a little so that the figure float to the top of the page you intend.

```
\begin{figure*}[!t]
  % normal figure code 
\end{figure*}
```